Telegraf error writing to outputs.sql: CREATE TABLE permission denied
I want my Telegraf to store measurements in SQL Server.
This is my telegraf.conf:
[[outputs.sql]]
driver = "mssql" 
data_source_name = "sqlserver://telegraf:foobar@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/telegraf"

I have no SQL Server Management Studio, so I created a user and database with DBeaver in the SQL Server with this script:
USE master;

CREATE LOGIN telegraf WITH PASSWORD = 'foobar';

CREATE DATABASE telegraf;

USE telegraf;
CREATE USER telegraf FOR LOGIN telegraf WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=telegraf;

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'telegraf';

CREATE SCHEMA telegraf AUTHORIZATION telegraf;

After this, I can connect to SQL Server with a telegraf login to create tables. But my Telegraf can't:

E! [agent] Error writing to outputs.sql: mssql: CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master'.

It looks like a bug, but I can't find hardcoded master DB neither in the Telegraf repo, nor in the MS go driver's one
I even tried to add telegraf user to the dbcreator role, as mentioned in https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/78390, but the result is the same..
What is the proper way to solve this?
$ telegraf --version
Telegraf 1.30.1 (git: HEAD@fb76952e)


As an FYI sys.sp_addrolemember is deprecated syntax. You should be using ALTER ROLE.

Hm, I executed ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [telegraf]; just now and have the same error after telegraf restart (CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'master') I's it necessary to make other operations with SQL Server?

Seems like it's ignoring the database specified in your data source string. Have you considered changing the SQL Login's default database, e.g.: ALTER LOGIN telgraf WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE='telegraf';?

I didn't say that it would change the behaviour, @viktorkho , just that you shouldn't be using a deprecated feature.

The telegraf docs are... rather light. Reading through the go-mssqldb docs it probably expects /?database=telegraf instead of /telegraf on the end of the data source string.

@AlwaysLearning seems to be right: "sqlserver://telegraf:foobar@${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}?database=telegraf" says another error =) about timestamp insertion.. Can you please post your advice like an answer, so I can accept it?
